# Powershell or batch script for collecting username, pcname, and Dell service tag(wmic identifyingname)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have been tasked with the job of collecting data from around 3-400 pcs and laptops. The task has to be done locally one by one on each machine for security reasons.
Can someone point me in the right direction of using a powershell or batch script that will get the details.
I tried using the following batch script:

`for /f "skip=1 tokens=1" %%A in ('wmic csproduct get identifyingnumber /value') do set asset=%%A
echo %%A,%computername%,%username% >> "file.csv"`

but this didnt work as the wmic command has a blank line at the end and overwrites the `%%A` with blank.
Please help a noob :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
    wmic csproduct get identifyingnumber /value
') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
    >>"file.csv" echo(%%b,%computerName%,%username%
)
```

The `/value` swith in `wmic` command asks for output in `key=value` format. The `for` will use the equal sign as a delimiter to tokenize the line, retrieving only the second token, that is, the value. As we are requesting the second token, and the only line that will contain two tokens is the line with the data, there is no need to skip or filter the output.

Also, the output from `wmic` contains an aditional carriage return at the end of the line so a second `for` loop is used to remove it.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        wmic csproduct get identifyingnumber^,name^,vendor /value
    ') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set "_%%b"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        wmic useraccount where (name^="%username%"^) get fullname /value
    ') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set "_%%b"

    >>"file.csv" echo(%_fullname%,%username%,%_vendor%,%_name%,%computerName%,%_identifyingnumber%
```

Simplified approach in this case. We are still retrieving the `key=value` format, so, use this format to directly set a environment variable with the value. An aditional query is needed to retrieve the full name for the current user (*note*: obviously the data is retrieved for *the user running the script*)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for your help. I would vote up but dont have the rep sorry.

Comment: Ok, so some things have changed. my manager now wants the name and vendor to be in the CSV. I know this can be done using wmic, so how do I add it to the command?
Ideally, I want the following to display:
<code>Users full name, Username, PC make, PC model, PC name, identifyingnumber</code> @mc-nd

Comment: @AnthonyBroadbent, answer updated. I don't see clear the user retrieval part, but I don`t know your users profiles. Probably you will have to adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually due this on every machine?  That seems kinda crazy when a single WMI call can get this remotely with no problem.

Here's an easier way to do it with Powershell locally.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios | Select-Object PSComputerName,SerialNumber  | Export-Csv -Path computerserials.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Add the -Computername param in there to do it remotely.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -Computername COMPUTERNAME | Export-Csv -Path computerserials.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

To iterate over a bunch of computer names create a text file with a single computer name per line and do something like this but that would require you do it remotely.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -Computername (Get-Content computerlist.txt) | Select-Object PSComputerName,SerialNumber | Export-Csv -Path computerserials.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

These examples are getting the computer name and the serial number.  If you need anything else its really easy to pull it directly out of WMI instead of using the kludge that is WMIC.